# Что означает +squeeze в названии пакета?

Tags: squeeze, php, debian

```
korwru@dserver:~$ dpkg --list | grep phpii  libapache2-mod-php5                 5.3.3-7+squeeze15            server-side,ii  php5                                5.3.3-7+squeeze15            server-side,ii  php5-cli                            5.3.3-7+squeeze15            command-lineii  php5-common                         5.3.3-7+squeeze15            Common files
```

"squeeze15" - означает количество заплаток/багфиксов? Если да, то почему оно одинаково для всех пакетов...

Можно ли где-то посмотреть что именно внедрили в этих заплатках?

Судя по офсайту последние версии, в которых нет уязвимостей - PHP 5.4.12 and PHP 5.3.22 released - значит версия 5.3.3-7 уязвима?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам и нашёл ответ.

http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/p/php5/php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze15/changelog

Версия 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 является безопасной и в ней закрыты все дыры, известные на текущий момент.

```
php5 (5.3.3-7+squeeze15) squeeze-security; urgency=high* [CVE-2013-1635] Fixed external entity loading* [CVE-2013-1643] Check if soap.wsdl_cache_dir confirms to open_basedir -- Ondřej Surý Mon, 04 Mar 2013 13:34:39 +0100
```

Answer (score 3):

"+squeeze" в имени пакета означает его адаптацию для Debian 6.0 "Squeeze". "squeeze15", насколько я понимаю, означает 15-ю модификацию самого дистрибутива, поэтому и одинаково для всех пакетов.